# FCM notifications not received using REST

Tags: android, rest, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm having an issue with my application : 
I succesfully configured my application to use FCM , and when i try to send a message by using the Firebase/Notification GUI, it works great. I receive the notification, by using the token or the app.

But my problem is that i want to use the REST api given by Google to POST notifications using my server.
Here is the POST data i send :

```
URL: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Method POST
Authorization: key=... (I have the autorisation to post the message)
Content-Type : application/json
Payload :
{
 "to":"{MyToken}",
  "data":{
        "message":"Bonjour comment ça va",
    }
}
```

I got this response that the notification was sent, but i don't receive anything on my phone.

```
{
"multicast_id": 
4752603394640553000
,
"success": 1,
"failure": 0,
"canonical_ids": 0,
"results": [
  {
"message_id": "0:1501772371010731%1496332af9fd7ecd"
}
],
}
```

And finally here is my Android code:

On te creation of the MainActivity :

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("jenkins");
String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
String msg = getString(R.string.msg_token_fmt, token);
Log.i("token",token);
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,msg,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

MyFireBaseInstanceID :

```
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

/**
 * Created by Alexandre Michaud on 02/08/2017.
 */

public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.
    }


}
```

MyFirebaseMessagingService :

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

/**
 * Created by Alexandre Michaud on 02/08/2017.
 */

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
        // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
        // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
        // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
        // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
        // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
        // messages. For more see: 
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
        // Not getting messages here? See why this may be: 
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            handleNow();


        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    /**
     * Handle time allotted to BroadcastReceivers.
     */
    private void handleNow() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Short lived task is done.");
    }

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     *
     * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
     */
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

And finally the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.alexandremichaud.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

So if someone could help me i would be verry happy! :)

Comment: you are sending notification to topic or Token? In rest code you use to: token but in app you subscribe to topic jenkins, try do this to see if you dont have problems with android code, send notification to topic or your test token

Comment: i tried both , but i think you didn't understand, in rest i send the notification ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) explains that there are two types of messages: notification and data.  You are sending a data message.  This will cause `onMessageReceived()` to be invoked and `handleNow()` to be called.  You should see log message *Short lived task is done*.  There will be no notification.

Depending on the behavior you want, you could send a notification message:

```
  {
    "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "Bonjour comment ça va",
      "title" : "Your Title"
    }
  }
```

or a message that contains both notification and data.

See also the [FCM Guide for handling messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive).